# How to login a user and send to shopping cart when he clicks on activation link in email

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Unregistered user can add items to cart, but needs to register before placing an order. 
When user clicks on activation link, he is left with message like 'Your account is activated. Login to continue shopping'.

I would like to activate and login user, and redirect him to shopping cart.
(lots of users just ignore the message and then complains that they cant place orders...)

My idea was to insert a variable in email activation url (to distinguish regular registration and registration during ordering), and in activation - if variable is set, do login and redirect.

Did manage to put variable in registration form (in checkout_register_form.php).
There are activate and _sendMail functions in com_user/controler.php that should do the rest (found url and message in _sendMail() and apropriate place for login and redirect in activate() ), but changes in that script just won't do anything :(

Any other way or suggestion why this won't work? Or am I working on wrong file?

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement you can achieve this task in two way.

1) Registration and Autologin

*) when the user comes in the registration form checkout page keep a hidden variable in the form.

*) then after registration in the com_users/controller/registration.php 
    contains the registration success section redirect area,Change this section only from check out.and force that user to login.

```
                    $app    = JFactory::getApplication();
                    $options = array();
            $credentials['username'] = $_POST['email'];
            $credentials['password'] = $_POST['password'];
            $error = $app->login($credentials, $options);
            $mainframe = &JFactory::getApplication();
            $mainframe->redirect(JURI::root().'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=checkout1',false);
```

This will do the registration and login at the same time user have no doubt or confusion.Also secure.(most shopping cart work like this).

2) After registration from email.

You should pass a key via email link and check that key and after activation.then push that user session enabled(This is not at all a right method for your requirement.)Security issues ,you should expired url access correctly to the login section .

I preffer first method most secure and joomla standard. just in the user manager the activation of user enable at the registration and use this method.

Hope this will helps..